# How can I use the package bytefield with the LaTeX class IEEEtran?

Tags: ieeetran, bytefield

Given the MWE

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bytefield}

\begin{document}    
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=10pt,bitheight=20pt]{8}
    \bitheader{0-7} \\
    \bitbox{1}{A} &
    \bitbox{1}{B} &
    \bitbox{1}{C} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
    \bitbox{1}{D} &
    \bitbox{1}{E} &
    \bitbox{1}{F} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
    \bitbox{1}{G} &
    \bitbox{1}{H} &
    \bitbox{1}{I} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
\end{bytefield}
\end{document}
```

it can be seen that the class IEEEtran  messes up the output produced by the bytefield package (compare compilation with class `article` (correct) and class `IEEEtran` (incorrect)).
How can I fix this? Note that my actual code uses a much more complex byte field with an additional TikZ overlay. I hope that fixing it in the MWE fixes it in my document as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a “feature” in `bytefield`, that relies upon `\lineskip` having the value 1pt, which it hasn't in `IEEEtran`.

You can fix it by doing a patch that sets `\lineskip` inside the `bytefield` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{bytefield}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpretocmd{\bytefield}{\setlength{\lineskip}{1pt}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{bytefield}[bitwidth=10pt,bitheight=20pt]{8}
    \bitheader{0-7} \\
    \bitbox{1}{A} &
    \bitbox{1}{B} &
    \bitbox{1}{C} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
    \bitbox{1}{D} &
    \bitbox{1}{E} &
    \bitbox{1}{F} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
    \bitbox{1}{G} &
    \bitbox{1}{H} &
    \bitbox{1}{I} &
    \bitbox{5}{X} \\
\end{bytefield}

\end{document}
```

[image]